# Can a https request header be faked as a security threat?

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, https

I am working on an app and would like to use http post requests to send data from client to server, on which the server uses the origin url from the client to allow to use our services, so my question is, can the http url from the client side be faked as a security threat to access my services, and if so, what other alternatives should i take?

An example is, if a client-side script running on a page from foo.com wants to request data from bar.com, in the request it must specify the header `Origin: http://foo.com`, and bar must respond with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://foo.com`.

What is there to stop malicious code from the site roh.com from simply spoofing the header Origin: `http://foo.com` to request pages from bar?

Comment: Any part of an HTTPS request is just as arbitrary as an HTTP request. The “S” doesn’t add anything in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

> What is there to stop malicious code from the site roh.com from simply
>   spoofing the header Origin

The browser is. CORS restrictions and headers only work in the browser and the browser is very strict about controlling them. This is specifically to prevent drive-by attacks from random scripts on random sites a user may unknowingly visit. It’s to protect the user of the browser.

However, absolutely nothing prevents a rogue server from sending an arbitrary HTTP request with any arbitrary headers to your server. I could do so from my command line using curl or such right now. These headers do not pose any sort of guarantee or protection for *your server*.

Answer (score 0):

'on which the server uses the origin url from the client to allow to use our services'
The origin url can be faked very easily.
Add a login with a token to prevent that.